# Why is callback in HTTPs node library being called twice? How to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, message-queue

I have a node code, which is esentially worker queue processor.
I'm running this in cluster of around 10 processes.

Each job processed by worker is making outgoing HTTPs request using function pasted below:

- Notice the done(); call, which is supposed to notify queue processor that the job processing has been completed - with either success or failure.
- For https requests i'm using standard node library with inclusion of "follow-redirects" module.

The problem i'm having, is that once every X minutes, one of my workers is crashing, with following error message.
From what i understand, it means that "done()" has been called multiple times inside "error_callback".

How can i prevent this behaviour?
Would embedding done() call inside exception handler work here? Is there a better solution?

```
[2019-07-19 22:19:23] error: uncaughtException: the deferred callback has already been called
Error: the deferred callback has already been called
    at callback (/root/node_modules/promise-callbacks/src/callbackBuilder.js:20:13)
    at Object.error_callback (/root/lib/ways.js:115:9) (function from this file is attached below)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at ClientRequest.eventHandlers.(anonymous function) (/root/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:17:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

```
        done(null, {host: this.host, code: statusCode}); //notify queue processor of success with inclusion of results
        done(e); //notify queue processor of failure with inclusion of error message
```

```
var http = require('follow-redirects').https;

exports.processLowLevel = function (url, index, done, SOCKET_TIMEOUT, HTTP_TIMEOUT, WRITE_RESULTS) {
    let url_parsed = require('url').parse(url);

    let response_callback = function (resp) {
        console.log(`[${index}] Response: ${this.host} - ${resp.statusCode}`);

        done(null, {host: this.host, code: resp.statusCode}); //notify queue processor of success
        return "";

    };

    let error_callback = function (e) {

        console.error(`[${index}] Error callback: ${this.host} ${e.message}`);

        e.host = this.host;

        done(e); //notify queue processor of FAILURE

        return "";

    };

    const options = {
        hostname: url_parsed.host,
        path: url_parsed.path,
        method: 'GET',
        timeout: HTTP_TIMEOUT * 1000,
    };

    options.maxRedirects = 4;


    let callback_data = {'host': url_parsed.host, 'index': index};

    const req = http.request(options, response_callback.bind(callback_data));
    req.on('error', error_callback.bind(callback_data));
    req.end();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this helps.. but in response_callback instead of:

```
done(null, {host: this.host, code: resp.statusCode}); //notify queue processor of success
        return "";
```

try

```
return done(null, {host: this.host, code: resp.statusCode});
```

and the same with error_callback, try:

```
return done(e);
```